TouchableOpacity in headerRight not working as expected in Expo Router (onPress only fires once or not at all)
Description
I'm experiencing a problem with headerRight configuration in expo-router where TouchableOpacity buttons aren't responding as expected. Specifically, the onPress event fires only once or sometimes does not trigger at all. I’ve tried multiple solutions and verified many possible causes, but I can't seem to resolve the issue. Any help would be appreciated.
Details
Expo SDK Version: 52.0.4
expo-router Version: 4.0.2
React Navigation Version: 6.0.2
Platform: iOS/Android (tested on physical devices)
Development Environment: Expo Go
Language: TypeScript
Problem Description
I am trying to use a TouchableOpacity component in headerRight of a Stack.Screen in expo-router. My expectation is that the button should be clickable multiple times, with each click triggering the onPress event. However, what I observe is:
The onPress event fires only on the first click or sometimes does not fire at all.
The button itself is visible in the header, but does not respond as expected to user interaction.
What I’ve Tried

Basic Configuration in RootLayout:
Defined headerRight directly within Stack.Screen in RootLayout.js as follows:

<Stack.Screen
  name="notes/index"
  options={{
    title: "Dodo",
    headerRight: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("Button pressed!")}>
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  }}
/>


This works for the first click, but the button becomes unresponsive afterwards.

Using useLayoutEffect to Update Header:
Added useLayoutEffect in my screen (notes/index.tsx) to update headerRight dynamically:

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("Pressed in useLayoutEffect!")}>
        <Text>Click Me Again</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  });
}, [navigation]);


Still, the button works initially but doesn't respond on subsequent clicks.
Expected Behavior
The button in headerRight should be clickable multiple times, with each click triggering the onPress handler.
Observed Behavior
TouchableOpacity in headerRight only responds on the first click or not at all after initial use.
The button is visually present in the header, but is not consistently registering interactions.
Steps to Reproduce
Create a stack navigator using expo-router.
Add a headerRight button using TouchableOpacity.
Run the app and navigate to the screen.
Try clicking the button — notice that onPress either fires only once or stops responding.
Questions
Has anyone else experienced this issue with headerRight? Are there known limitations when using expo-router for header buttons?
Is there an alternative approach for adding interactive elements to the header that works reliably?

Hi @Francesca, I have just noticed the same issue. For me:

headerRight still works with iPhone Simulator, but not Android physical device
It was fine before I upgraded Expo to the latest version, including the new architecture.

I need to do some further investigation before raising a bug.

Looks like it's an accepted issue. See https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/29489.
Try using onPressIn instead of onPress.

I was able to solve the issue, thanks to Luke's comment. The problem is not just limited to TouchableOpacity, but also affects other components such as Button and Pressable when using the onPress event in headerRight or headerLeft of Stack.Screen. By changing onPress to onPressIn, the issue was resolved for all these components. Here's the updated code:


<Stack.Screen
  name="notes/index"
  options={{
    title: "Dodo",
    headerRight: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPressIn={() => console.log("Button pressed!")}>
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  }}
/>



Thanks again to Luke for pointing me in the right direction!
